# POST request with multipart form-data including image in iOS Swift, using Almaofire

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire, multipartform-data

I have been trying to make a call to an API in my iOS application written in Swift / SwiftUI, but I have not been successful in my attempts.

Here is the request in cURL:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'my_api_url' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'apikey: my_api_key' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'scale=fit' \
  -F 'format=PNG' \
  -F 'output_type=cutout' \
  -F 'image=@test_image.png;type=image/png'
```

I am using Alamofire, which I installed via CocoaPods, to help format and send the request in my application. Below is my code:

```
func postRequestAlamofire() {    
    // imageToSegment is defined in the View as follows
    // @State private var imageToSegment: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "k_test")
    if let imageToSegment = imageToSegment {
        if let rawImageData = imageToSegment.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
                            
            let httpHeaders: HTTPHeaders = [
                "accept": "application/json",
                "apikey": "my_api_key",
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            ]
            
            // AF is from the Alamofire HTTP networking library
            AF.upload( multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                multipartFormData.append("fit".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "scale")
                multipartFormData.append("PNG".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "format")
                multipartFormData.append("cutout".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "output_type")
                multipartFormData.append(rawImageData, withName: "image", fileName: "test_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }, to: "my_api_url", method: .post, headers: httpHeaders)
            .response { (afResponse) in
                print(afResponse)
                
                if let data = afResponse.data {
                    print("Data: \(data)")
                    
                    if let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) {
                        print(parsedData)
                    }
                }; if let response = afResponse.response {
                    print("Response: \(response)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have figured out that the image file I am trying to append to the `multipartFormData` is not going through with the request, so I am wondering how to properly include that?

Comment: 500 is usually a server issue, there is no way to help you with the code you have provided –

Comment: Unrelated but: `"fit".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!` => `Data("fit".utf8)`, much simpler.